# fortran beginner - writing variable to output file

Tags: fortran

I am starting to work with a CFD fortran program, and want to update the variables that it writes to an output file.

I want to output several columns, I and J coordinates(`IL` and `JL`), Water Surface Elevation (`SURFEL`), Bottom Elevation of coordinate (`BELV`), Depth of Water (`HP`) and finally, and this is where I have the question, the Maximum Water Surface Elevation of the coordinate during the simulation (`SURFELMAX`).  `L` refers to a specific I,J coordinate, `LA` is the last coordinate in the simulation

So far I have:

```
DO L=2,LA  
   SURFEL=BELV(L)+HP(L)
   IF (SURFEL.GT.SURFELMAX)THEN
      SURFELMAX=SURFEL
   ELSE IF (SURFELMAX.GT.SURFEL) THEN 
      SURFELMAX=SURFELMAX
      WRITE(10,200)IL(L),JL(L),SURFEL,SURFELMAX 
   ENDIF 
ENDDO
```

Everything works ok other than the `SURFELMAX`, in which the highest recorded surface elevation that occurred in any coordinate in the whole domain is written for each coordinate, i.e. the column is filled with the same value, the highest experienced in the whole domain during the simulation.

Would I need to first allocate an array for `SURFELMAX`, and have `SURFEL` checked against it each time to see if it has increased? If so could somebody point me in the right direction for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the requirements correctly, then you want to calculate `SURFELMAX` before you start writing out.  This could simply be:

```
SURFELMAX = MAXVAL(BELV(2:LA)+HP(2:LA))
WRITE(10,200) (IL(L), JL(L), BELV(L)+HP(L), SURFELMAX, L=2,LA)
```

(or even as a single line).

It appears I didn't understand correctly; I'll try again - keeping the above as a warning to others.

It seems that you do indeed want `SURFELMAX(2:LA)` where each element is the highest in a given cell to date.

```
do L=2, LA
  SURFELMAX(L) = MAX(SURFELMAX(L), BELV(L)+HP(L))  ! Store the historical maximum
  WRITE (10,200) IL(L), JL(L), BELV(L)+HP(L), SURFELMAX(L)
end do
```

where, initially, `SURFELMAX` has been set to a sufficiently small value.  You could also explicitly calculate `SURFEL` if that is needed.

Comment: thank you for your quick reply
- I'm not sure this would work for what I am after - e.g. the software simulates a river flow over a few months, writing water levels to the file every 15 minutes. I am looking to have an output file that has recorded the maximum water level experienced in each grid cell individually over the course of the whole simulation. 

I guess I need to make an array of size L of water levels at each time step, and update another array if any higher values are found during that time step? Does that sound correct? How would I go about writing that? thank you for your help

Comment: thank you both for your helpful replies, I think I will be able to write what I need now.  I'm really grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If this is time dependent, then you will have to define a 2-d array `SURFELMAX` of size (1:LA,1:T) (T = number of time steps, LA = number of active coordinates).

Then increment the time step (say, the iterator is called I_T) outside of the loop through the domain.
Finally assign the maximum value at each coordinate to the SURFELMAX(I_T,L)

Comment: thank you both for your helpful replies, I think I will be able to write what I need now.  I'm really grateful for your help.